# JQuery wait for page to finish loading before starting the slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, preload

I have a site with a rotating header image (you've all seen them). I want to do the following:

1. Load the entire page plus the first header image
2. Start the header image slideshow transitioning every x seconds or when the next image has finished loading, whichever is later

I haven't really need an example that truly does this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably already know about $(document).ready(...). What you need is a preloading mechanism; something that fetches data (text or images or whatever) before showing it off.  This can make a site feel much more professional.

Take a look at [jQuery.Preload](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/01/jquerypreload.html) (there are others). jQuery.Preload has several ways of triggering preloading, and also provides callback functionality (when the image is preloaded, then show it).  I have used it heavily, and it works great.

Here's how easy it is to get started with jQuery.Preload:

```
$(function() {
  // First get the preload fetches under way
  $.preload(["images/button-background.png", "images/button-highlight.png"]);
  // Then do anything else that you would normally do here
  doSomeStuff();
});
```

Comment: The only real anwser : there is no easy way to do it. Use a plugin.

Comment: e-satis: I'm not sure why you believe the use of a plugin is the only "real" answer.

Comment: because of: never re-write pieces of code, you will always find the piece of code doing the same and written better

Answer (score 24):

you can try

```
$(function()
{

$(window).bind('load', function()
{

// INSERT YOUR CODE THAT WILL BE EXECUTED AFTER THE PAGE COMPLETELY LOADED...

});
});
```

i had the same problem and this code worked for me. how it works for you too!

Comment: @Marin could be wrong but I think bind is deprecated for stuff like this.  not very useful reply i admit

Answer (score 15):

Well the first can be achieved with the document.ready function in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

The changing image can be achieved with any number of plugins

- http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/
- http://www.matto1990.com/jquery/slideshow/

If you wish you can check if images are loaded with the complete property.  I know that at least the malsup jquery cycle slideshow makes use of this function internally.

Comment: I don't think any of these will wait to transition until the next iamge has loaded though right?

Answer (score 8):

The $(document).ready mechanism is meant to fire after the DOM has been loaded successfully but makes no guarantees as to the state of the images referenced by the page.

When in doubt, fall back on the good ol' window.onload event:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  //your code here
};
```

Now, this is obviously slower than the jQuery approach.  However, you can compromise somewhere in between:

```
$(document).ready
(
  function()
  {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImage");

    var intervalId = setInterval(
                        function()
                        {
                          if(img.complete)
                          {
                            clearInterval(intervalId);
                            //now we can start rotating the header
                          }
                        },
                        50);
  }
);
```

To explain a bit:

1. we grab the DOM element of the image
   whose image we want completely
   loaded
2. we then set an interval to
   fire every 50 milliseconds.
3. if, during one of these intervals, the
   complete attribute of this image is
   set to true, the interval is cleared
   and the rotate operation is safe to
   start.

Comment: window.onload = function() is a bad idea, it prevents you from setting onload from anything else or will erase any other "onload".

Comment: @e-satis: To avoid overwriting the hooks that are already attached to the `window.onload`, attach your function with jQuery: `$(window).load(function () {});`

Comment: @e-satis: I mentioned window.onload specifically because the event handler code assigned to it is guaranteed to execute after images have loaded, which is different from the behavior of the jQuery ready function and somewhere at the other extreme of what the OP is looking for.  You're right, there are better ways to attach events, but I didn't want to lose sight of the key points I was trying to convey.

Comment: @Andreas: Good to know about the Load function.

Answer (score 3):

did you try this ?

```
$("#yourdiv").load(url, function(){ 

         your functions goes here !!!

});
```

Comment: So would that comment, and this one. :o

Answer (score 1):

If you pass jQuery a function, it will not run until the page has loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //your header rotation code goes here
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the "page has loaded" mean that all of the other images will be loaded as well?

Comment: No, it only means that the dom has been created.

Comment: If you really need to wait for the page to finish loading, you could do:
$(window).load(function() {//your code });

Comment: This notation is just a shortcut for document.ready. It has nothing to do with the page load event.