# $(document).ready or $(window).load for jQuery cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using Jquery Cycle to scroll images, i am currently using $(document).ready,
 the problem is the images are half loaded and the cycle effect starts,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft,scrollLeft,scrollLeft,scrollLeft' ,
        speed:  1000,
        pause:   3
         });
 });
```

Should i use $(window).load which waits for all images to load before starting the effects,
The problem with this is images will be stacked on top of the other.

So Kindly suggest a solution to my problem

Comment: for the div with ID `gallery` make style `display: none` . If this does not solves problem then add in js code `$("#gallery").show();`. Try it before and after cycle code and see the results. You should not use $(window).load for cycle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430854/jquery-wait-for-page-to-finish-loading-before-starting-the-slideshow

Answer (score 0):

```
#gallery { width: SOMEDEFAULTWIDTH; height: SOMEDEFAULTHEIGHT; } 
#gallery img { display:none; }
```

To avoid images to be stacked on top of the other hide the images by `display: none` jquery cycle plugin will show them when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library to help you load all your images and then load them when you need to

http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/

Answer (score 0):

You also use jQuery(window).load() event that is fired after whole content is loaded.

Use like this.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {

 $('#gallery').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft,scrollLeft,scrollLeft,scrollLeft' ,
    speed:  1000,
    pause:   3
     });

});
```

Hope it helps to you.